# Java Generics usage difficulty

Tags: java, generics

i'm a newbie to java..i'm having difficulty in understanding generics. with what i understood i wrote the following demo program to understand Generics but there are errors..help required.

```
class GenDemoClass <I,S> 
{
    private S info;
    public GenDemoClass(S str)
    {
        info = str;
    }
    public void displaySolidRect(I length,I width)
    {
        I tempLength = length;
        System.out.println();
        while(length > 0)
        {
            System.out.print("          ");
            for(int i = 0 ; i < width; i++)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
            length--;
        }
        info = "A Rectangle of Length = " + tempLength.toString() + " and Width = " + width.toString() + " was drawn;";     
    }

    public void displayInfo()
    {
        System.out.println(info);
    }
}

public class GenDemo
{
    public static void main(String Ar[])
    {
        GenDemoClass<Integer,String> GDC = new GenDemoClass<Integer,String>("Initailize");
        GDC.displaySolidRect(20,30);
        GDC.displayInfo();
    }
}
```

if i replace type variables I and S with `Integer` and `String` in the `GenDemoClass` then code seems to work..
the errors are

```
error: bad operand types for binary operator '>'
                while(length > 0)
                             ^
  first type:  I
  second type: int
  where I is a type-variable:
    I extends Object declared in class GenDemoClass
```

Comment: you cannot compare numbers and `I` which can be pretty much anything. Consider what would happen if you'd declare `GenDemoClass<String, String>`

Comment: yes i had considered that but i was trying a demo..i assumed only passing Integer..so according to that assumption i was thinking on the lines of I being a placeholder for Integer and hence went further with the coding..if this would work then my assumption would be right so..thanks for the response..

Comment: if you already solved the issue, you may wanna accept @michaels answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that most objects do not work with the > operator.

If you declare that your type `I` must be a subtype of `Number`, then you can convert the instance of type I to an int primitive in the comparison. For instance

```
class GenDemoClass <I extends Number,S> 
{


public void displaySolidRect(I length,I width)
    {
        I tempLength = length;
        System.out.println();
        while(length.intValue() > 0)
        {

        }
```

At this point you're sunk because you cannot modify the `length` value like you want to - it's immutable. You can use a plain int for this purpose.

```
public void displaySolidRect(I length,I width)
    {
        int intLength = length.intValue();
        int intHeight = width.intValue();
        System.out.println();
        while(intLength > 0)
        {
           // iterate as you normally would, decrementing the int primitives
        }
```

In my opinion this is not an appropriate use of generics, as you don't gain anything over using the primitive integer type.

Comment: thanks for the response..yeah this is just a demo program to understand Generics so did not give heed to the programs usefulness..also i'm having problems with the second type too i.e when i pass the String type...should i extend String class for the second type??

Comment: Sure you can say S extends String. But really why even use a generic for S in that case?

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you pass something that isn't an Integer in to the `I length` file? Right now you're not saying that it should be any specific type, so if you were to pass in, say, a String, what would happen on this line?

```
while(length > 0)
```

Here you're assuming `length` is an integer, when you very clearly defined it generically as an `I`.

Comment: yes this thought crossed my mind at the very begining but i was more involved in solving the other problem first..thanks for the response

Answer (score 1):

You should check `instanceof` before use

```
if (I instanceof Integer){ 
   // code goes here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `>` op is not valid for an arbitrary class `I`.